# Should I replace my tire

Tags: tires, safety, sidewall-damage

[image][image]
Should I replace my tire or is it fine to drive on

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

The damage is in a part of the tire that is not going to impact the strength. There are no threads or ply layers visible. The cut is mostly a smooth transition, which means no stress points to expand.

Keep your tire pressure at specified figures and you'll be good to go.